# Filter NSArraycontroller Core Data before searching

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, filtering

I have an NSArrayController managing contacts stored in Core Data and presented in a NSTable. The table provides a search field to the user to look for contacts by name. Everything is implemented in Swift using Cocoa bindings and works well.
Now I want to add an additional filter before the user types his search string. The filter should limit the contacts via an additional attribute like a creation date. How can this be done? Via modifying the predicate or do I need to subclass NSArrayController?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the fetch predicate?

Comment: Just an idea: bind the search field predicate to a property `searchPredicate` of the view controller. Bind the array controller filter predicate to a property `filterPredicate` of the view controller. Implement `didSet` of `searchPredicate` and calculate `filterPredicate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I tried the approach mentioned by Willeke. Setting a default fetch predicate for the array controller initially with the Interface Builder and executing the following code every time the date date value changes, worked fine.

```
 let fetchRequest = ContactArrayController.defaultFetchRequest()
 fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "events.@max.eventDate < %@", lastDate as NSDate)
 try? ContactArrayController.fetch(with: fetchRequest, merge: false)
```

where event is a related entity to the entity in the array controller.

However this appears to be an overhead to me, as the data needs to be fetched every time into the array controller instead of just applying a filter

Maybe there are better solutions